# Why is my attempt to display an alert to the user throwing an error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want a user using my app on mobile to see a dismissable alert telling them that the site shouldn't be used on mobile. However, when I test the code I've tried, I get an error.

I have tried importing the packages I've seen alluded to on websites and writing the alert text I want users to see.

```
render() {
  if (isMobile){
    return (
      <Alert>
        <Alert.Heading>Mobile Browser Detected</Alert.Heading>
        <p>
          This page is not optimized for mobile. Please view this page on a desktop.
        </p>
      </Alert>
    );
  }

  return (...);  // For when it's not on mobile
}
```

I expect the screen to show a little dismissable alert that can be canceled but not completely stop the person from viewing the page. Instead, I get an error (when using a mobile simulator via 'inspect element'):

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `App`.

Comment: How are you importing the `Alert` component? Are you returning anything when `isMobile` is false?

Comment: Please show the imports you have. It may be you're importing the `Alert` component incorrectly.

Comment: When the browser isn't mobile, it shows correct. My imports are `import { Button, Popup, Message } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import { Provider as AlertProvider } from 'react-alert';
import AlertTemplate from 'react-alert-template-basic';
import  { Alert }  from 'react-bootstrap';
import { useAlert } from 'react-alert';`

Answer (score 0):

Like the warning says,

> you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I believe the proper way to import Alert is:

```
import Alert from 'react-bootstrap/Alert'
```

You can read more at the React-Bootstrap [docs](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/alerts/) for proper use cases.